# Is there a way to tell what technology was used to build an Android app?

Tags: android, apk

I have an Android App I downloaded and installed, I have also extracted the APK,

Is there some way from the apk file to tell what programming language was used to write the program?

What languages can be determined and which ones cannot?

Comment: try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017341/how-to-determine-if-an-app-is-native-or-html5

Comment: Many (all?) jvm languages bring their stdlib extensions. For example, if you see usage of `kotlin.*` namespace, it's a good chance that kotlin was used here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76175825/18568328

Answer (score 6):

Normally most android app is build using the following texhnologies:---

1. React Native app
2. Cordova app
3. Native java/kotlin app

To determine the technology, you need to decompile the app first using [this link](https://www.apkdecompilers.com/)

Then look for "assets" folder. Normally, asset folder should be present at the very top of application hierarchy.

Then you can determine the app technology by the following prediction:--

1. If asset folder is present and there have any file with the extension ".bundle"(mainly the file name is "index.android.bundle") then the app is build using React Native.
2. If the assets folder contain a folder name "www" and "assets/www" contain the following file/folder structure then it is a cordova app.
   [image: Click to view the file/folder structure]
3. If neighter 1 or 2 is true then the app may be written using native code, i.e using java/kotlin

Comment: Neither 1 or 2 if true :( but i hardly believe that the app was written using native code :(

Comment: None of 1 and 2 are correct , `assets` folder was empty !

Answer (score 4):

You can do a reverse engineering : (https://www.apkdecompilers.com/ or http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) decompile the apk and see the code and its programming language.

Comment: decompiling apk converts language to java most times.. Maybe always..Even if it is react native or kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

Not an accurate way to get the specific technology, but **through adb**, you could check the activity name of an app.

Usually when you open different activities or pages, with native technology the ActivityName will be different like below (Playstore app):

[image]

whereas in hybrid apps such as Ionic e.g, it is usually bundled up into one, hence the only activity will be `MainActivity`... like the [Hamilton](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hamilton.app) app made with flutter:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understood, what did you mean?